# Exterior Tiling falling off of front step

Tags: tile, stairs

The front step of my house is concrete with tiling on top (installed by the previous owner). Recently the tiling starting falling off. You can see from the picture below that between the concrete structure and tile is a bed of loose gravel. See the below image (underneath the gravel is the concrete structure) [image: gravel bed]

[image: side view]
Is this a suitable substrate for tiling? Can I just add new grout on top of the gravel and reset the fallen tiles?

Comment: "Mortar", not "grout". It's not clear to me whether that's old mortar or simply sand. If it's mortar, it's badly degraded. How deep is it? Are you in a freezing climate?

Comment: Yes, it's a freezing climate. That sand or degraded mortar is about 1/4 inch deep.

Comment: To tell the truth I see no evidence of any Portland cement in that sand. did someone throw some sand in to fix a broken piece or they all just sitting on a bed of sand.

Comment: I think they are all just sitting on a bed of sand. The adjacent tile is almost 100% loose. I can pry it up the rest of the way to see.

Comment: It looks as though whoever laid those tiles thinks that tiles are held together with the grout between them and not much else. I would lift them all and redo the job...

Comment: @brhans, ok, and simply scrape the sand/gravel out of there and re-level with solid mortar?

Comment: Pretty much that yes - as long as you have a solid something not much more than about 1/2" below.